# Mysql Joining on IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a two tables one for news items and one for images.

**News Table Structure**

- ID - numeric
- newstitle - text
- newsdesc - text
- newsimages - text

**Image Table Structure**

- ID - numeric
- medianame - text

So a common news record would be:
ID = 1, newstitle="asdasfa", newsdesc="afsdgsgs", newsimages="1,2"

And the image table record would be:
ID=1, medianame="image.jpg"

I am trying to create a select statement that reads the data from the news table but provides me with the image name from the image table instead of the IDs.

If there is anything else ive left out let me know

Thanks

Comment: could you share query also ?

Comment: Bad table design. Normalize your tables, i.e. don't store comma-separated lists. Have a `news_image` table instead that contains related `news_id` and `image_id`. Then writing the query will be straight-forward: you'll join on the IDs.

Comment: There does not appear to be a relationship between news table and image table and without that a join is not possible.

Comment: @P.Salmon Any two tables can be meaningfully joined. But here presumably there is something in common--a news event id.

Comment: Hi. Your description of your desired result is not clear. Exactly what columns do you want, and what rows? (If you want a row for ever id, what if it has no image? Can we have image for an event that doesn't yet have a name etc?) What is the role of an ID in each table--what does a row i a table say? This question is absolutely basic, and a faq; read your textbook & google what you want to do & also 'stackexchange homework'. Read [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text, and [mcve]. Please put in some effort before you ask a question. This question is poor per a bunch of different clicks.

Comment: @P.Salmon ThorstenKettner points out that 'newsimages="1,2"' suggests that those ints are presumably Image ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function

Example:

```
SELECT `news`.`ID`, `news`.`newstitle`, `news`.`newsdesc`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(`images`.`medianame` SEPARATOR ',') AS `newsimages`
FROM `news`
LEFT JOIN `images` ON FIND_IN_SET(`images`.`ID`,`news`.`newsimages`)
GROUP BY `news`.`ID`
```

P.S. if you have (or planning to have) a big amount of rows, then you must to normalize the data.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but leads to a very slow query, so I wouldn't recommend this. It's way better to normalize the data model.

Comment: Yes, it is not a best solution, but in this situation it's only one possible solution. This solution will work pretty well if tables does not have a big amount of rows. (-;

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comments.
I have inherited this as the developer has done a runner and the portal using this is live.
I agree the data needs to be normalised but this is not an option at this stage.
I'll try your solution and if it can't be done then I will just have to report that it can't be done.
Thanks again

Answer (score -2):

it seems to be simple

```
SELECT N.*, I.medianame FROM News_Table N left join Image_Table I 
ON N.Id=I.Id
```

I have assumed that tables names are News_table and Image_table respectively and that one news piece may have more than one image.

Comment: No. An image ID is not a news ID. One identifies a news record, the other an image record.

Comment: so you need the cross table with both IDs.

Comment: Yes, a bridge table containing related news ID and image ID. So far it seems the news table's column `newsimages` contains a comma-separated list of image IDs instead. One could still join on this, but would get a very slow query. So the OP should better normalize their tables :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The question *doesn't say* what IDs are used for.

Comment: @philipxy: That's true, but `news.newsimages = '1,2'` looks very much like a comma-separated list of image IDs.

Comment: The question is unclear. Don't answer; comment, downvote, close vote, etc.

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner  news.newsimages = '1,2' are ID's in the image table.